# XSLT apply function to element value and output result in new copy of xml document

Tags: function, xslt

How do I apply a function to an element value and output the result

This is my source

```
<tests>
  <test>
    <row name="C/A">-0.1</row>
    <row name="C/B">-0.2</row>
    <row name="C/C">Text1</row>
  </test>
  <test>
    <row name="C/A">1.1</row>
    <row name="C/B">2.2</row>
    <row name="C/C">Text2</row>
  </test>
</tests>
```

Stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="test/row[@name='C/A'] | test/row[@name='C/B']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select=". * 1000"/>
    </xsl:copy>    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to call a function on rows with attributes "C/A" and "C/B".
In my example stylesheet I am multiplying by 1000 (however I would like to apply a more complicated formula).

This is the desired outcome

```
<tests>
  <test>
    <row name="C/A">-100</row>
    <row name="C/B">-200</row>
    <row name="C/C">Text</row>
  </test>
  <test>
    <row name="C/A">1100</row>
    <row name="C/B">2200</row>
    <row name="C/C">Text</row>
  </test>
 </tests>
```

This is my output, the name attribute is not being copied. Also how do I can a function on the row values and return the result. For example, the multiplier might depend on the 'row' value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tests>
  <test>
    <row>-100</row>
    <row>-200</row>
    <row name="C/C">Text1</row>
  </test>
  <test>
    <row>1100</row>
    <row>2200</row>
    <row name="C/C">Text2</row>
  </test>
</tests>
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you explain what problem you are actually encountering? Apart from the `name` attribute not being copied, you are getting the desired output. So, just replace `<xsl:value-of select=". * 1000"/>` with what ever the more complicated formula is. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I have made some edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy the attributes, simply add a line to select them to the template

```
<xsl:template match="test/row[@name='C/A'] | test/row[@name='C/B']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    <xsl:value-of select=". * 1000"/>
  </xsl:copy>    
</xsl:template>
```

In terms of applying a function, consider using a named template...

```
<xsl:template match="test/row[@name='C/A'] | test/row[@name='C/B']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    <xsl:call-template name="myFunction" />
  </xsl:copy>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="myFunction">
  <xsl:param name="value" select="." />
  <xsl:value-of select="$value * 1000"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This uses the value of the current node as the default value, but you can pass in a different value of the parameter if required.

Comment: Much appreciated Tim